# jQuery - Combine multiple click functions when adding/removing class using id

Tags: jquery, function, click, addclass

I'm sure there must be a more elegant (and less repetitive!) way of doing this.
Is there a way to combine the following functions?

```
 $('#one').click(function() {
$('#container').removeClass();
$('#container').addClass('one');return false;});

$('#two').click(function() {
 $('#container').removeClass();
$('#container').addClass('two'); return false;});

$('#three').click(function() {
$('#container').removeClass();
$('#container').addClass('three');   return false; });
```

...and so on  etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#one,#two,#three').click(function(){
    $('#container')[0].className = this.id;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: THAT's what I had in my head - just couldn't get it to my fingertips! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can type

```
$('#one,#two,#three').click(function(){
  $('#container').removeClass();
  $('#container').addClass(this.id);
  return false;
})
```

Comment: `this.id` should suffice. No need to jquerify `this`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#one, #two, #tree').click(function(event) {
  $('#container').removeClass();
  $('#container').addClass($(this).attr('id'));
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Note that in the OP `return false;` does `event.stopPropagation()` as well as `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: I know, but I feel `event.preventDefault()` more "elegant" as requested by Brainache

Comment: My point is that you changed the behaviour instead of just refactoring. `return false;` in a jQuery event handler means both, stopping propagation and preventing the default action. You are just preventing the default action here.